# can't install ipa to iOS8 with command line

Tags: windows, ant, command-line, ios8, ipa

For some reason I cannot install the IPA file on to the iOS8 device using Ant.
I've read countless posts on StackOverflow and searched the world wide web with no luck. Any help appreciated.

I'm on Windows 7 and using Ant to run the command line codes.

Ant Script below:

```
<macrodef name="install-ios">
    <attribute name="ipa"/>
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="${sdk.home}/bin/adt${bin.bat_ext}" failonerror="true">            
            <arg value="-installApp"/>
            <arg value="-platform"/>
            <arg value="ios"/>
            <arg value="-package"/>
            <arg value="@{ipa}"/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

When I run the script I get an error on the Output:

"exec return 13"

I've tried looking it up, but cannot find anything.

Comment: some of the `<arg value=` things look suspect to me (but I'm not an `ant` expert by any means). If you can get your command to work on the command-line, it would be helpful to show the complete command on 1 line as part of your question. Good luck.

Comment: The break down of this to the command-line looks like this:   
   D:/Users/rbl/AppData/Local/FlashDevelop/Apps/flexairsdk/4.6.0+15.0.0/bin/adt.bat
 
 
-installApp -platform ios -package ../dist/superbute_explorer-mobile-ad-hoc.ipa 
  
 Any thoughts?

Comment: I would try adding spaces at the end of `-installApp ` and `-package ` (in the Ant script). Good luck.